# MacVim gets all settings from ~/.vimrc, but not the colors and I have to source it again

Tags: vim, syntax-highlighting, macvim, vim-syntax-highlighting

I am using the following ~/.vimrc with MacVim 7.4 on MacOS X Mavericks:

```
set guifont=Menlo:h14
set encoding=utf8
set mouse=a
set expandtab
set ts=8
set showcmd
set nocompatible
set backspace=2
set viminfo='20,\"50
set history=50
set ruler
set si
set hlsearch
syntax on
set bg=light
hi Cursor     term=inverse   ctermfg=black                guifg=black  guibg=green
hi Visual     term=inverse   ctermfg=yellow ctermbg=black guifg=yellow guibg=black
hi Comment    term=inverse   ctermfg=grey   ctermbg=black guifg=white  guibg=black
hi Identifier term=NONE      ctermfg=black                guifg=black
hi Constant   term=underline ctermfg=darkred              guifg=red
hi Statement  term=bold      ctermfg=blue                 guifg=blue
hi PreProc    term=NONE      ctermfg=black                guifg=black  gui=underline
hi Special    term=NONE      ctermfg=black                guifg=black
hi Type       term=bold      ctermfg=blue                 guifg=blue
```

and can see that the editor takes all the settings from that file (the font family and its size, the show ruler and tab settings, ...), but not the colors:

[image: screenshot 1]

Only after I issue the command `:so ~/.vimrc` does it take my color settings too (red and blue with inverted comments):

[image: screenshot 2]

Does anybody please know, what is happening, why doesn't MacVim pick up the syntax colors too?

Below is the `:version` information:

```
VIM - Vi IMproved 7.4 (2013 Aug 10, compiled Aug 10 2013 18:40:52)
MacOS X (unix) version
Compiled by Douglas Drumond <douglas@eee19.com>
Huge version with MacVim GUI.  Features included (+) or not (-):
+arabic          +emacs_tags      +localmap        +postscript      +textobjects
+autocmd         +eval            -lua             +printer         +title
+balloon_eval    +ex_extra        +menu            +profile         +toolbar
+browse          +extra_search    +mksession       +python          +transparency
++builtin_terms  +farsi           +modify_fname    -python3         +user_commands
+byte_offset     +file_in_path    +mouse           +quickfix        +vertsplit
+cindent         +find_in_path    +mouseshape      +reltime         +virtualedit
+clientserver    +float           +mouse_dec       +rightleft       +visual
+clipboard       +folding         -mouse_gpm       +ruby            +visualextra
+cmdline_compl   -footer          -mouse_jsbterm   +scrollbind      +viminfo
+cmdline_hist    +fork()          +mouse_netterm   +signs           +vreplace
+cmdline_info    +fullscreen      +mouse_sgr       +smartindent     +wildignore
+comments        -gettext         -mouse_sysmouse  -sniff           +wildmenu
+conceal         -hangul_input    +mouse_urxvt     +startuptime     +windows
+cryptv          +iconv           +mouse_xterm     +statusline      +writebackup
+cscope          +insert_expand   +multi_byte      -sun_workshop    -X11
+cursorbind      +jumplist        +multi_lang      +syntax          -xfontset
+cursorshape     +keymap          -mzscheme        +tag_binary      +xim
+dialog_con_gui  +langmap         +netbeans_intg   +tag_old_static  -xsmp
+diff            +libcall         +odbeditor       -tag_any_white   -xterm_clipboard
+digraphs        +linebreak       +path_extra      -tcl             -xterm_save
+dnd             +lispindent      +perl            +terminfo
-ebcdic          +listcmds        +persistent_undo +termresponse
   system vimrc file: "$VIM/vimrc"
     user vimrc file: "$HOME/.vimrc"
 2nd user vimrc file: "~/.vim/vimrc"
      user exrc file: "$HOME/.exrc"
  system gvimrc file: "$VIM/gvimrc"
    user gvimrc file: "$HOME/.gvimrc"
2nd user gvimrc file: "~/.vim/gvimrc"
    system menu file: "$VIMRUNTIME/menu.vim"
  fall-back for $VIM: "/Applications/MacVim.app/Contents/Resources/vim"
Compilation: clang -c -I. -Iproto -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -DFEAT_GUI_MACVIM -Wall -Wno-unknown-p
ragmas -pipe  -DMACOS_X_UNIX -no-cpp-precomp  -g -O2 -U_FORTIFY_SOURCE -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE
=1
Linking: clang   -L.    -L.     -L/usr/local/lib -o Vim -framework Cocoa -framework Carb
on       -lncurses  -liconv -framework Cocoa   -fstack-protector -L/usr/local/lib  -L/Sy
stem/Library/Perl/5.12/darwin-thread-multi-2level/CORE -lperl -lm -lutil -lc -framework
Python   -framework Ruby
```

Answer (score 15, accepted):

MacVim is sourcing its default `gvimrc` *after* your `~/.vimrc`. It contains this snippet:

```
" Load the MacVim color scheme.  This can be disabled by loading another color
" scheme with the :colorscheme command, or by adding the line
"   let macvim_skip_colorscheme=1
" to ~/.vimrc.
if !exists("macvim_skip_colorscheme") && !exists("colors_name")
    colorscheme macvim
endif
```

What happens is simple: MacVim's default colorscheme overrides your `:hi` commands when you launch Vim and your `:hi` commands override the default colorscheme when you source `~/.vimrc`.

The fix is simple too: turn your `:hi` commands into a real colorscheme as per Ingo's answer.

Also, `set background=light` is only useful in a colorscheme so move that line as well.

Comment: Another fix is to do what the quoted comments suggest:  add `:let macvim_skip_colorscheme=1` to your vimrc file.

Comment: Another thing I did was to create a .gvimrc and add the below sole line ```source ~/.vim/colors-overriders```.

Answer (score 6):

This isn't a direct answer, but you should extract all the `:hi` commands from your `~/.vimrc` into a separate (private) colorscheme, e.g. `~/.vim/colors/mine.vim`. Prepend the following preamble:

```
hi clear
if exists("syntax_on")
    syntax reset
endif
let g:colors_name = "mine"
```

Then choose that colorscheme via

```
:colorscheme mine
```

in your `~/.vimrc`.

#### Benefits

- Should fix your problem.
- Uses the proper abstractions provided by Vim.
- Reduces the size of your `.vimrc`, making it more manageable.
- Allows you to switch colorschemes on the fly.
- Restores your colors when you temporarily turn `:syntax off`.

Answer (score 3):

The MacVim is a gvim really, so you can have a .gvimrc that would be a mac specific colortheme config. Eg. I normally have a base .vimrc which I use on all unix systems where I normally disable all syntax colours but tint the comments. Like you said it won't work in MacVim so I have a .gvimrc which is perfect for setting colours for macvim, provided I never use gvim anywhere.